# Raspberry Pi Send Requests to two networks on Dual WAN Setup?

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi-os

I have two networks with approximately 150 machines each that are running on their own WANs (for bandwidth purposes). Each of the WANs has a Modem/Router combo running its own custom OS and each is responsible for DHCP IPv4 assignment on their respective networks.

I wish to install a Raspberry Pi (latest 32-bit) with two NICs to bridge the networks and run traffic analysis on both networks from the same Raspberry Pi. So far I have been having difficulty configuring the Pi to be able to send requests to both Networks. Instead the primary eth0 seems to be trying to take care of all of the requests despite my attempts to setup some alternative routes.

```
profile static_eth0
static_ip=192.168.1.2/24
static_router=192.168.1.1
```

The secondary NIC is a USB-to-Ethernet adapter, IP is `192.168.8.1/24` with gateway of `192.168.8.1`

In short, I am unsure how to configure this to make it work properly. I have tried several `route add` entries without much luck.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. What exactly means "to make it work *properly*"? What are you trying to achieve and what does not work as expected? What requests are you trying to send to the networks? Show example commands if possible. Show the output of `netstat -r`.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do BUT the code fragment you posted will not do anything on its own. Why are you making life difficult for yourself by using static IP?